# laravel mysql timeout when connecting to remote digital ocean database server on local network

Tags: mysql, laravel, doctrine, digital-ocean

My laravel installation is having some issues connecting to the MySQL database. I am also using laravel doctrine.

The mysql server is on a separate digital ocean droplet.

Mysql server listens on a non standard port, is bound only to the local network interface (eg 10.131.xx.xx)

The mysql database has a non root user which has host access configured

The mysql server has iptables configured to only allow the webserver ip to connect to the non standard port on bound ip

my .env file is configured as so

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_DATABASE=$CORRECT_USER
DB_HOST=$CORRECT_TARGET_LOCAL_IP
DB_USERNAME=$CORRECT_DB_USR
DB_PASSWORD=$CORRECT_PASS
DB_PORT=$CORRECT_PORT
```

to sanity check my env

i have tried connecting directly to mysql as followed

> $ mysql -u$CORRECT_DB_USR -p$CORRECT_PASS -h$CORRECT_TARGET_LOCAL_IP
>   --port=$CORRECT_PORT $CORRECT_USER

which connects correctly

as well as telnetting the target as followed

> $ telnet $CORRECT_TARGET_LOCAL_IP $CORRECT_PORT

which prints

> Escape character is '^]'. [
>   my-os-and-version1"||xgpK(iqJmysql_native_password

but when i run the command php artisan doctrine:schema:create

the following errors are shown

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                      An
>   exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connect     ion
>   timed out
>
> ```
>                                               [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]             SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
> ```
>
> Connection timed out
>
> ```
>                                               [PDOException]                                  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed
> ```

out

I have tailed the ufw.log and the mysql error log, on the mysql server no packets are dropped by the firewall and no incorrect credential errors are thrown from the mysql log

does any one have any idea what this might be